# rails vue.js deep nested (attributes of attribute)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I created one nested form by watching [gorails tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Vt20jpoUiI)  It is fine and i done it. Issue started when i want to creat nested model under on other nested model. I have `Survey` model and it is main model. Then i added `Question` model and made form with vue.js. So I added `Choice` model under question ( you can notice in survey controller params) First problem is; i don't know how i can define/implemen in vue.js control.(hello_vue.js) And second importan point is: how i can create form elements in new.html

This is my survey.rb model:

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:user_id, :name, questions_attributes:[:id,:survey_id, :title, :qtype, :_destroy, choices_attributes:[:id,:question, :ctext]])
    end
end
```

This is nested model of Survey : question.rb:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    enum qtype: [:multiple_choice, :check_boxes, :short_answer]
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :choices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, allow_destroy: true
end
```

So finaly vue.js file:

```
 import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
 import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
 import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

Vue.component('app', App)
 document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
      var element = document.getElementById("survey-form")


if (element != null){
    var survey = JSON.parse(element.dataset.survey)
    var questions_attributes = JSON.parse(element.dataset.questionsAttributes)
    var choices_attributes = JSON.parse(element.dataset.choicesAttributes)
    questions_attributes.forEach(function(question) { question._destroy = null })
    survey.questions_attributes = questions_attributes

    var app = new Vue({

    el: element,
    //mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter],  
    data: function(){
        return { survey: survey }

    },

    methods:{
        addQuestion: function(){

            this.survey.questions_attributes.push({
                id: null,
                title:"",
                qtype:"",
                _destroy: null


            })
        },
       removeQuestion: function(index) {
          var question = this.survey.questions_attributes[index]

          if (question.id == null) {
            this.survey.questions_attributes.splice(index, 1)
          } else {
            this.survey.questions_attributes[index]._destroy = "1"
          }
        },
        undoRemove: function(index) {
          this.survey.questions_attributes[index]._destroy = null
        },

                saveSurvey: function() {
          // Create a new survey
          if (this.survey.id == null) {
            this.$http.post('/surveys', { survey: this.survey }).then(response => {
              Turbolinks.visit(`/surveys/${response.body.id}`)
            }, response => {
              console.log(response)
            })




          // Edit an existing survey
          } else {
            this.$http.put(`/surveys/${this.survey.id}`, { survey: this.survey }).then(response => {
              Turbolinks.visit(`/surveys/${response.body.id}`)
            }, response => {
              console.log(response)
            })
          }
        },


        existingSurvey: function() {
          return this.survey.id != null
        }

    }   
   })
    }


 })
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :div,
    id: "survey-form",
    data: {
      survey: survey.to_json(except: [:created_at, :updated_at]),
      questions_attributes: survey.questions.to_json,

    } do %>

<label>Survey Name</label>
<input qtype="text" v-model="survey.name">

<h4>Questions</h4>
<div v-for="(question, index) in survey.questions_attributes">
    <div v-if="question._destroy == '1'">
      {{ question.title }} will be removed. <button v-on:click="undoRemove(index)">Undo</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <label>Question</label>

      <input qtype="text" v-model="question.title" />

     <label>Qestion qtype</label>
  <select v-model="question.qtype">
  <option v-for="qtype in <%= Question.qtypes.keys.to_json %>"
    :value=qtype>
    {{ qtype }}
  </option>
</select>


      <button v-on:click="removeQuestion(index)">Remove</button>
    </div>

    <hr />
  </div>

  <button v-on:click="addQuestion">Add Question</button>

<br>

<button v-on:click="saveSurvey" >Save Survey</button>


    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this same tutorial and started running into issues using JSON.parse with more complex nested attributes. Try using Jbuilder to build your JSON objects and look into the gon gem to pass your Rails variables into Javascript. It'll be much easier to query your database and pass the results into your Javascript file using the nested naming that Rails needs. For example...

```
survey = @survey

json.id survey.id

json.survey do
  json.(survey, :user_id, :name)  
  json.questions_attributes survey.questions do |question|
    json.(question, :id, :title, :qtype, :_destroy)
    json.choices_attributes question.choices do |choice|
      json.(choice, :id, :ctext)
    end
  end
end
```

It allows you to do things like...

```
var survey = gon.survey
```

Instead of...

```
var survey = JSON.parse(element.dataset.survey)
```

And you can pass `gon.jbuilder` from your controller action and have your defined JSON object ready and available in Vue.

Comment: Awesome solution Travis! also I remember your question that you have sent here and other forums. You can understand that how I know and how much time i spend to find solution :) thanks again

Comment: Dear Travis, do you have any sample codes on github, etc that you made correct? I’ll be so happy If you can share with me. (I just started vue side after recretion the project) thanks!

Comment: I have set `var survey = gon.survey` on vue and it is working fine. but `choices_attributes` is still undefined. how can i define in vue.js as nested of question_attributes?

Comment: If the nested objects are being created in your form, you can just define them in your Vue instance "data" attribute as needed and reference them in your form using "v-model". For editing, you'll need the jbuilder file that takes the database queries and populates your Vue instance with the right nested attribute naming ("_attributes", etc.).

Comment: You'll want to have a *.json.jbuilder view file for whatever action you're calling (edit, show, etc) that has the structure you need in your vue data object. See my example above for formatting.