# How do I give my Vue components access to active record objects on my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, controller, backend

I inherited a project built on Rails that uses Vue for its front-end. All the views are rendered through Vue, but the routing and models follow the standard Rails MVC pattern.

I want to render some objects stored in Active record inside a Vue component.

I also want to build a form in Vue with CRUD functionality with the Active record database.

When I pass instance variables from the Rails controller to the Vue view it does not work.

```
#controller.rb
def index
  @projects = Project.all
end

#view.html.erb
<% @projects.each do |e| %>
  <div><%= e.information %></div>
<% end %>
```

I have to directly call active record inside the view itself like so:

```
#controller.rb
def index
end

#view.html.erb
<% @projects = Project.all %>
<% @projects.each do |e| %>
  <div><%= e.information %></div>
<% end %>
```

So to summarise, the two questions I need to answer are:
1. How do I pass active record objects into a vue component and render it in the front-end?
2. How can I write a Vue form to creat,edit & update active record objects in the database?

Comment: Unrelated, but a collection of `Project`s should be called `@projects`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.
It's been a long day and I'm jetlagged.

Comment: To the user who posted earlier and now whose post disappeared:
Thanks, your suggestion of using Rails Helpers worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actually be able to use the data in VueJS you should convert the data to JSON and load it in to the vuejs data block.

That way you could do something like

```
<div v-for="project in projects">{{project.information}}</div>
```

You can then update this data in vue and it will automatically change the text on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For a technique I’m using, check out [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180179/4693218].